# what package should i import in java so that i can use imread method or cvLoadImage method of opencv?

Tags: java, opencv

I am trying to use opencv 2.4.6 in java, i import the org.opencv.core.Core but imread is not defined still.
I hava read the api book @ http://docs.opencv.org/java/, but i still can't find a method to load a image?
I need you help, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to import

```
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
```

for `imread` (imread is a static method so to call it you would need to write `Highgui.imread`)

and if you are using javacv then the `cvLoadImage` will be in

```
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.cvLoadImage;
```

Comment: thank you, my demo is running now!

Comment: actually , after imported org.opencv.highgui.Highgui, I need to write Highgui.imread to call this method.

Comment: @Axe : that is because imread is a static method...